# orchard module new appeared in the list

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6, orchardcms-1.7

I've followed this [tutorial](http://skywalkersoftwaredevelopment.net/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-3) to create a simple module based on the tutorial and I followed it as it says, yet I can't find the new added module in my modules list, the class library is placed under Modules folder and it has exactly what it was explained in the tutorial. any help & suggestion would be helpful. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would follow this tutorial instead: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Command-line-scaffolding. Use the command line to create modules in Orchard and set IncludeInSolution to true.

Comment: Yeah. Use the Codegen utility to bootstap your new module.